# How does my decorator-class apply the signatur of the passed function?

Tags: python, generics, decorator

I have created a functionlity so that the initialization of a class can be done in another class without replicating the whole method. It works, but I dont understand why.

I have several device-classes:

```
class TestClass:

    # Purpose of that method explained later
    @classmethod
    def create_instance(cls, x: int, y: int, z: int):
        return cls(x, y, z)

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

The creation and management of those devices should happen in a somewhat centralized manner.
But I wanted to prevent having to redefine every init-signature of every device, which is why I have searched for a way to copy the signature of the init method.

*Yes, I know about args and kwargs, but with that approach, the user does not get that helpful tooltip regarding the accepted params aso*

I have found a way to achieve my goal like that:

1. define a TypeVar:

```
F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])
```

2. define a class decorator:

```
class copy_signature(Generic[F]):
    def __init__(self, _: F) -> None: pass
    def __call__(self, wrapped: Callable[..., Any]) -> F: return wrapped
```

3. define the get_instance-method in the device-classes (like shown in the first code-block)
4. annotate the create-methods in the service

```
class DeviceService:

    test_device: TestClass = None

    @copy_signature(TestClass.create_instance)
    @classmethod
    def create_test_device(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> TestClass:
        cls.test_device = TestClass.create_instance(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls.test_device

    @classmethod
    def get_test_device(cls) -> TestClass:
        return cls.test_device
```

Now everthing seems to work exactly like it would have after recreating the init-method

[Useful tooltip I want the users to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Sj5.png)

BUT: How is this working? I've read through multiple explanations of the decorator-functionality and still dont get why this is working in the first place.

The decorator has an init-method which is doing nothing (pass)
It is needed though, since I am passing more arguments than the default init accepts: self and a reference to the TestClass.create_instance function.

But, when I dont even use the passed reference, why do I need to pass it?
If I dont pass the function, there is no reference at all to the function whose signature I want to copy.

Comment: The value passed to `__init__` method provides the type-checker with a concrete type for the TypeVar `F`, which is then reflected in the return type of the `__call__` method, which is what acts as the decorator. So it doesn't matter that that value isn't used at runtime, because it is providing useful info to the type-checker.

Comment: Thank you! If you formulate that as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its simplest form a decorator is syntax sugar for a function which takes a function as an argument and returns a function.

But in Python when we say 'function' we usually implicitly mean "callable". By adding a `__call__` method we can make any class instance callable.

So here we have defined a class whose instances will behave as a decorator.

The value passed to `__init__` method provides the type-checker with a concrete type for the TypeVar `F`, which is then reflected in the return type of the `__call__` method (which is the part that implements the decorator).

So it doesn't matter that that value isn't used at runtime, because it is providing useful info to the type-checker.

It is the "type-checker" (I'm using the term loosely...) in your IDE which provides contextual hints based on the method signature.